# Arguments in docker_compose.yml throwing error, but not with docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am in some desperate help. I am atempting to translate this docker run command:

```
docker run -d -p 5434:5432 --name postgres-2 livingdocs/postgres:14.4 standby -d "host=host.docker.internal port=5433 user=postgres target_session_attrs=read-write"
```

which works flawlessly, but when I attempt to convert it to docker_compose.yml:

```
  postgres-2:
    image: livingdocs/postgres:14.4
    container_name: postgres-SLAVE
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres2:/tmp/data
    entrypoint: "/scripts/entrypoint standby"
    command:
      - host=host.docker.internal
      - port=5433
      - user=postgres
      - target_session_attrs=read-write"
```

It throws:

```
pg_basebackup: error: too many command-line arguments (first is "host=host.docker.internal")

Try "pg_basebackup --help" for more information.
```

After I save the yml file and execute: `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans`

I've tried the online conversion tools and about 300 variations, but I cannot get to function the same as docker run.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks like in your original docker command the whole string is passed as a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Why in your `docker-compose.yml` are you setting `entrypoint`, when your `docker run` command does not have a `--entrypoint` option?  You've also removed the `-d` option from the invocation, and you're passing the remaining options as individual arguments rather than the single string you're using in the `docker run` invocation.

The equivalent to your `docker run` command line would be:

```
  postgres-2:
    image: livingdocs/postgres:14.4
    container_name: postgres-SLAVE
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    command:
      - standby
      - -d
      - "host=host.docker.internal port=5433 user=postgres target_session_attrs=read-write"
```

I've removed the `volumes` stanza, since you're not using any volumes on the `docker run` command line.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

```
  postgres-2:
    image: livingdocs/postgres:14.4
    container_name: postgres-SLAVE
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres2:/tmp/data
    entrypoint:
      - standby
    command: "--host host.docker.internal --port 5433 --user postgres"
```